# expiry date for month and year

Tags: javascript, date

having some trouble trying to figure this out, complete novice when it come to JavaScript. I'm trying to validate a form, more specific the expiry date of a credit card.
e.g jan 2011 would be invalid but dec 2011 would be valid etc.
This is what i have so far:

```
function ExpiryDate() {

var year
var months

today = new Date();
    expiry = new Date(year, month);
    if (today.getTime() > expiry.getTime())

    return false;
else
    return true;
};
```

my form reads:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="default.html" onsubmit="return Validate(this);">

<p>Expiration Date: Month

<select name="ExpMon" id="ExpMon" title="select a month"> 
        <option value="1">Jan</option> 
        <option value="2">Feb</option> 
        <option value="3">Mar</option>
        <option value="4">Apr</option> 
        <option value="5">May</option> 
        <option value="6">June</option> 
        <option value="7">July</option> 
        <option value="8">Aug</option> 
        <option value="9">Sept</option> 
        <option value="10">Oct</option> 
        <option value="11">Nov</option> 
        <option value="12">Dec</option> 
 </select>      

 Year:
 <select name="ExpYear" id="ExpYear" title="select a year"> 
     <option value="2010">2010</option> 
     <option value="2011">2011</option> 
     <option value="2012">2012</option> 
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
     <option value="2014">2014</option> 
     <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select></p> 

</form
```

I'm not to sure how to use the id's to get what I want, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance. note:I have a function called Validate which validates a text field in my form so i could attach it to this somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var year = document.getElementById("ExpYear").value;
var month = document.getElementById("ExpMon").value;
```

If you prefer, you can use the names instead; you'd have to get Validate to pass the form element in as a parameter, but then you can use `theForm.ExpYear.value` and `theForm.ExpMonth.value`.

Note: many people dislike statements of the form `if (today.getTime() > expiry.getTime()) return false; else return true;` when you can simply write `return today.getTime() <= expiry.getTime();`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I found your advice to be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Neil has answered your question about how to get the values (+1).  I just wanted to add that, IMHO, it would be a better user experience not to allow your users to choose an unacceptable expiry date in the first place.

This is a little more effort but basically, by responding to the selected month you could look at the current time and then reset the allowable years based on that month.  Similarly, based on the chosen year, the set of allowable months would change based on the current time.

Rather than letting the user make a mistake and then firing up a warning, just don't allow the mistake to be possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

The following will take the user input, create a date object, and then compare it to today's date.  One key item is that it will find the last day of the current month so that even if today is May 3 and the user select "May 2011" (which is valid for a credit card transaction), it will return "valid".

```
function CheckDate() {
    var selectedDate = new Date (document.getElementById("ExpYear").value,document.getElementById("ExpMon").value)
    var nextmonth = selectedDate.setMonth(selectedDate.getMonth() + 1);
    var last_date_of_selected_date = new Date(nextmonth -1);
    var today = new Date();
    if (today > selectedDate) {
        alert("Invalid");
    }
    else {
        alert("Valid");
    }
}
```

Here's a working jsFiddle to see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/cPApB/3/

Comment: Much better to use an ISO8601 date format than a region-specific one. Also, the date of both months should be set to the same (say the 1st) and the hour, minutes and seconds of today should be set to zero. The easiest way is: `var today = new Date(); today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth());`

Comment: @RobG: Good point on the ISO8601 date format.  I've updated my answer accordingly.  However, it still compares the current date to the last day of the selected month instead of both being the 1st like you suggest.  The OP is comparing the date to valid credit card expiry dates which are valid until the end of the month.

Comment: Is it just me not noticing something, or does the `last_date_of_selected_date` variable not even get used?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var today = new Date();
var expDate = new Date($("#cart-expyear").val(),($("#cart-expmonth").val()-1)); // JS Date Month is 0-11 not 1-12 replace parameters with year and month
if(today.getTime() > expDate.getTime()) {
    console.log("Your Card is expired. Please check expiry date.");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this simple validation

```
var expiryYear = $('#<%# DataBinder.Eval (ddlYear,"ClientID") %> option:selected').val();
var expiryMonth = $('#<%# DataBinder.Eval (ddlValidMonths,"ClientID") %> option:selected').val();
            var currentUserDate = $('#<%# DataBinder.Eval (hdnFieldJsonDate,"ClientID") %>').val();
            if (currentUserDate != null && expiryMonth != null && expiryYear != null) {
                currentUserDate = JSON.parse(currentUserDate);
                if (expiryMonth > 0 && expiryYear > 0) {

                    //If the Expiry Year smaller than Current Year, then validation failed
                    if (expiryYear < currentUserDate.Year)
                    { args.IsValid = false; }
                    //If the Expiry Year larger than Current Year, then validation passed
                    else if (expiryYear > currentUserDate.Year)
                    { args.IsValid = true; }
                    //If the Expiry Year is same as Current Year, and if Expiry Month is smaller than current month, then validation failes, else passed.
                    else if (expiryYear == currentUserDate.Year) {
                        if (expiryMonth < currentUserDate.Month)
                            args.IsValid = false;
                        else
                            args.IsValid = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                { args.IsValid = true; }
            }
```